# Android back to main activity from MusicService notification

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-music-player

I'm working on a music player for android and i'm stuck at this problem.

By now i can play a song with musicservice and send it to background, i also display a notification with current playing song.

What i need is to re-open the main activity from the song notification and continue playing the song, it actually starts the desired activity but the music service is re-created and it stops the current playing song.

Here is my code.

MusicService.java

```
public class MusicService extends Service implements
    MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener,
    MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener,
    MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {

private final IBinder musicBind = new MusicBinder();

//media player
private MediaPlayer player;

//song list
private ArrayList<SongModel> songs;

//current position
private int songPosition;

public MusicService() {
}

public void onCreate() {
    //create the service
    super.onCreate();

    //initialize position
    songPosition = 0;

    //create player
    player = new MediaPlayer();

    initMusicPlayer();
}

public void initMusicPlayer() {
    //set player properties
    player.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
    player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    player.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    player.setOnErrorListener(this);

}

public void setList(ArrayList<SongModel> theSongs) {
    songs = theSongs;
}

public class MusicBinder extends Binder {
    public MusicService getService() {
        return MusicService.this;
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return musicBind;
}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    player.stop();
    player.release();
    return false;
}

public int getPosition() {
    return player.getCurrentPosition();
}

public int getCurrenListPosition() {
    return songPosition;
}

public int getDuration() {
    return player.getDuration();
}

public boolean isPlaying() {
    return player.isPlaying();
}

public void pausePlayer() {
    player.pause();
}

public void stopPlayer() {
    player.stop();
}

public void seekToPosition(int posn) {
    player.seekTo(posn);
}

public void start() {
    player.start();
}

public void playSong() {
    try {
        //play a song
        player.reset();

        SongModel playSong = songs.get(songPosition);
        String trackUrl = playSong.getFileUrl();

        player.setDataSource(trackUrl);
        player.prepareAsync();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    if (mp.getCurrentPosition() == 0) {
        mp.reset();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
    mp.reset();
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    //start playback
    mp.start();

    SongModel playingSong = songs.get(songPosition);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NavDrawerMainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);

    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_playing)
            .setTicker(playingSong.getTitle())
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setContentTitle(playingSong.getTitle())
            .setContentText(playingSong.getArtistName());

    Notification notification = builder.build();
    startForeground((int) playingSong.getSongId(), notification);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    stopForeground(true);
}

public void setSong(int songIndex) {
    songPosition = songIndex;
}
```

}

DiscoverSongsFragment.java

```
public class DiscoverSongsFragment extends Fragment
    implements MediaController.MediaPlayerControl {

JazzyGridView songsContainer;
SongsHelper songsHelper;
SongsAdapter songsAdapter;
ArrayList<SongModel> songsArrayList;
ConnectionState connectionState;

Context mContext;
private static View rootView;

SongModel currentSong;
SeekBar nowPlayingSeekBar;
final Handler handler = new Handler();

// this value contains the song duration in milliseconds.
// Look at getDuration() method in MediaPlayer class
int mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds;

View nowPlayingLayout;
boolean nowPlayingLayoutVisible;

TextView nowPlayingTitle;
TextView nowPlayingArtist;
ImageButton nowPlayingCover;
ImageButton nowPlayingStop;

private MusicService musicService;
private Intent playIntent;
private boolean musicBound = false;
private boolean playbackPaused = false;

private int mCurrentTransitionEffect = JazzyHelper.SLIDE_IN;

public static DiscoverSongsFragment newInstance() {
    return new DiscoverSongsFragment();
}

public DiscoverSongsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_discover_songs, container, false);
    mContext = rootView.getContext();
    setupViews(rootView);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    if (playIntent == null) {
        playIntent = new Intent(mContext, MusicService.class);
        mContext.bindService(playIntent, musicConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        mContext.startService(playIntent);
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (isPlaying()) {
        showNowPlayingLayout();
        primarySeekBarProgressUpdater();
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    mContext.stopService(playIntent);
    musicService = null;
    super.onDestroy();
}

private void hideNowPlayingLayout() {
    nowPlayingLayoutVisible = false;
    nowPlayingLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    Animation animationFadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.fade_out);
    nowPlayingLayout.startAnimation(animationFadeIn);
}

private void showNowPlayingLayout() {
    nowPlayingLayoutVisible = true;
    nowPlayingLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    Animation animationFadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.fade_in);
    nowPlayingLayout.startAnimation(animationFadeIn);
}

private void setupViews(View rootView) {
    songsHelper = new SongsHelper();
    songsArrayList = new ArrayList<SongModel>();
    connectionState = new ConnectionState(mContext);
    songsAdapter = new SongsAdapter(mContext, songsArrayList);

    nowPlayingLayout = rootView.findViewById(R.id.nowPlayingLayout);
    nowPlayingLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    nowPlayingLayoutVisible = false;

    songsContainer = (JazzyGridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.songsContainerView);
    songsContainer.setTransitionEffect(mCurrentTransitionEffect);
    songsContainer.setAdapter(songsAdapter);
    songsContainer.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            musicService.setSong(position);
            musicService.playSong();

            if (playbackPaused) {
                playbackPaused = false;
            }

            currentSong = songsArrayList.get(position);

            // gets the song length in milliseconds from URL
            mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds = getDuration();

            if (currentSong != null) {
                nowPlayingTitle.setText(currentSong.getTitle());
                nowPlayingArtist.setText(currentSong.getArtistName());
                nowPlayingCover.setImageBitmap(currentSong.getCoverArt());
            }

            primarySeekBarProgressUpdater();

            if (!nowPlayingLayoutVisible) {
                showNowPlayingLayout();
            }
        }
    });

    nowPlayingSeekBar = (SeekBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.nowPlayingSeekbar);
    nowPlayingSeekBar.setMax(99);

    nowPlayingTitle = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.nowPlayingTitle);
    nowPlayingArtist = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.nowPlayingArtist);
    nowPlayingStop = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.nowPlayingStop);
    nowPlayingStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isPlaying()) {

                currentSong = null;
                playbackPaused = false;
                musicService.stopPlayer();
                mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds = 0;
                nowPlayingSeekBar.setProgress(0);
                hideNowPlayingLayout();

            }
        }
    });

    nowPlayingCover = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.nowPlayingCover);
    nowPlayingCover.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, SongDetailsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("Title", currentSong.getTitle());
                intent.putExtra("Artist", currentSong.getArtistName());
                intent.putExtra("Album", currentSong.getAlbumName());
                intent.putExtra("Genre", currentSong.getGenre());
                intent.putExtra("CoverUrl", currentSong.getCoverArtUrl());

                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    getSongs();
    hideNowPlayingLayout();
}

private void getSongs() {

    if (!connectionState.isConnectedToInternet()) {

    }

    songsAdapter.clear();

    String songsUrl = Constants.getAPI_SONGS_URL();
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(songsUrl, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray jsonArray) {

            if (jsonArray != null) {

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    try {

                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        SongModel song = songsHelper.getSongFromJson(jsonObject);
                        songsAdapter.add(song);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
        }
    });

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonArrayRequest);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
}

/**
 * Method which updates the SeekBar primary progress by current song playing position
 */
private void primarySeekBarProgressUpdater() {
    nowPlayingSeekBar.setProgress((int) (((float) getCurrentPosition() / getDuration()) * 100));

    //if (isPlaying()) {
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            primarySeekBarProgressUpdater();
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
    //}
}

@Override
public void start() {
    musicService.start();
}

@Override
public void pause() {
    playbackPaused = true;
    musicService.pausePlayer();
}

@Override
public int getDuration() {
    if (musicService != null && musicBound && musicService.isPlaying()) {
        return musicService.getDuration();
    }
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int getCurrentPosition() {
    if (musicService != null && musicBound && musicService.isPlaying()) {
        return musicService.getPosition();
    }
    return 0;
}

public int getCurrentListPosition() {
    if (musicService != null && musicBound && musicService.isPlaying()) {
        return musicService.getCurrenListPosition();
    }
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void seekTo(int pos) {
    musicService.seekToPosition(pos);
}

@Override
public boolean isPlaying() {
    if (musicService != null && musicBound && musicService.isPlaying()) {
        return musicService.isPlaying();
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public int getBufferPercentage() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public boolean canPause() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean canSeekBackward() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean canSeekForward() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public int getAudioSessionId() {
    return 0;
}

//connect to the service
private ServiceConnection musicConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        MusicService.MusicBinder binder = (MusicService.MusicBinder) service;
        //get service
        musicService = binder.getService();
        //pass list
        musicService.setList(songsArrayList);
        musicBound = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        musicBound = false;
    }
};
```

}

(The fragment also re-creates itself when navigating through drawer menu items)

I hope somebody can help me achieve this. I dont know how to maintane the state when re-starting the MainActivity (by the way, im using navdrawer to hold fragments)

Answer (score 0):

Include the currently playing song in your notification intent.  Update the intent as the song changes.  Include the flag to clear top and the flag to update current in the notification intent. :( *sorry* IDK if I have the flags right for your situation but you'll have a place to do more research.

In your service where you create the notification intent.

```
        // link the notifications to the recorder activity
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, KmlReader.class);
        resultIntent
                .setAction(ServiceLocationRecorder.INTENT_COM_GOSYLVESTER_BESTRIDES_LOCATION_RECORDER);
        resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent
                .getActivity(context, 0, resultIntent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

        return mBuilder.build();
    }
```

Then in main `onCreate` check the bundle for the name of the currently playing song and display it.  Notice how I check for the existence of a bundle key before using it.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    String intentaction = intent.getAction();

    // First Run checks
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // first run init
```

...

```
    } else {
        // get the saved_Instance state
        // always get the default when key doesn't exist
        // default is null for this example
        currentCameraPosition = savedInstanceState
                .containsKey(SAVED_INSTANCE_CAMERA_POSITION) ? (CameraPosition) savedInstanceState
                .getParcelable(SAVED_INSTANCE_CAMERA_POSITION) : null;
```

...